# Iframe is set to click event . it works for First click after opening page. But not works for Second time. Please help On this

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-maps-api-3, gis

Using google map API V3, I have created One html page. It perfectly load gmap and i set button to load another web based map(mapmyindia.com) in Iframe. basically it took the parameter(lat/long) from gmap and fetch into that frame to load. it works on 1st click and navigate the  current gmap location. After panning it another location and clicking to submit button it supposed to load current location of gmap into Iframe. But it doesn't work for second time. Kindly review my code and Help......!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var map;
var marker
function initialize()
{
var mapOpt = {
  center:new google.maps.LatLng(20.6588,80.9562),
  zoom:6,
  mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapOpt);



google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousemove', function(event) {
        document.getElementById("pp").value = map.getCenter().lat() + "," +map.getCenter().lng();
        });


}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load',initialize);
function copyText()
{
var xy=map.getCenter().lat()+ "," +map.getCenter().lng();

document.getElementById("latlng").value=xy;
document.getElementById("Zoom").value=map.getZoom();
}

function copyText1()
{
var xy=map.getCenter().lat()+ "," +map.getCenter().lng();
}



function OfferTwo(){
var mmy = map.getCenter().lng() + "," +map.getCenter().lat();
var sUrl = document.getElementById('offer2').src;
//var Zm= map.getZoom();
var Zm= '8';
document.getElementById('offer2').src = 'http://maps.mapmyindia.com/embed.html#current:'+Zm+','+mmy;
}


</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type= "text" ID=latlng>
<input type="text" ID=Zoom size="5" maxlength="2">
<input type ="text" ID="pp" >
<button onClick="copyText()">Submit</button>
<button onClick="OfferTwo()">Go To MMy</button>
<p Id="mmyurl">MamMyIndia Link</p>



<br><br>
<div id="googleMap"style="width:700px;height:500px;"></div>
<iframe id="offer2" Width="700" Height ="500"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

your script only changes the hash inside the url, when you click on the button the 2nd time the browser will try to jump to an anchor instead of reloading the map.

Add a changing parameter to the QUERY_STRING:

```
document.getElementById('offer2').src 
  = 'http://maps.mapmyindia.com/embed.html?'+
     new Date().getTime()+'#current:'+Zm+','+mmy;
```

Comment: Thanks alot Dr.Molle..! it works now. But if suppose i chaged `Zm` value to 0. it cant give that zoom level..?

Comment: It appears that mapmyindia.com supports a zoom from 15(lowest) to 0(highest) , while google maps supports opposite zoom from 0(lowest) up to 24(highest, depending on the mapType). You must calculate the  zoom for mymapindia and cannot set the value from google maps directly.

Comment: OK I got it. can please let know how to get these two window side by side. Thanks .......!